# New Teams doesn't capture OBS virtual camera and flakes out

Tags: microsoft-teams, obs-studio

Old Teams works fine and has for years. As soon as the "New Teams" app came out, it wouldn't capture my OBS virtual camera once the meeting starts.

It recognises the virtual camera, but it only grabs a still image and when I join the meeting, it shows that still image in the "preview" size, and the rest of the video screen is blank, meaning I can't see any other attendees or anything else until I stop my video in Teams.

- MS Teams is up-to-date
- OBS Studio both at v29 and v30.0.0
- Both have been reinstalled as part of this troubleshooting
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the virtual camera separately

If I use the button to use "Old" Teams, everything works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Was the new Teams installed from the Microsoft Store while the old one was not? Try: In Teams settings "Disable GPU hardware acceleration" and restart Teams. Question: Is there a difference between capturing the Teams window and capturing a screen area that includes the window?

Comment: Teams was installed from the Microsoft site from my corp account. GPU Acceleration is not an option anymore. I'm not capturing the screen. I'm trying to use the OBS virtual camera.

Comment: Are you starting Teams prior to OBS? One [report](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/obs-virtual-camera/m-p/1569254) recommends it.

Comment: Yep, one then the other and vice versa

Comment: The OBS [Virtual Camera Troubleshooting](https://obsproject.com/kb/virtual-camera-troubleshooting) might be useful, if you haven't done it already.

Comment: I tried the separate uninstall, but since I reinstalled OBS from scratch, I didn't have hope that it would work.

Comment: Found [this advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/teams/comments/17xl1ju/teams_is_not_displaying_obs_virtual_camera_anymore/) : "change the output from 4k to 1080".

Comment: @harrymc heh, they reference my post about this on the OBS forums. I'm already at 1080, though, but I'll chase them on Reddit to see how they actually did that.

Comment: @harrymc yep, I'm already at the reduced resolution. No joy.

Comment: Found [another post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-not-working-with-obs-virtual-camera-23-2-2021/m-p/2158739), somewhat older, with two workarounds at its end. You might try them.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem in the past, but this is different. I've tried those suggestions, too. Very frustrating.

Comment: There's probably no good solution, except filing bug reports with Microsoft and OBS. Or perhaps using another screen camera product that works better with Teams.

Comment: I'm starting to think so. But I'm curious as to why this isn't a wider problem.

Comment: I tried v29 of OBS, but it's the same problem. I'm starting to think that it's a local environment problem, but I can't imagine what factors are invovled.

Comment: You probably need to stay with the old Teams as long as you can, and file a bug report for the new one. There are other reports about problems with the new Teams, so yours is just one more of them.

Comment: Not terribly useful except as a data point: I've got New Teams and OBS 30 here and the "OBS Virtual Camera" is working as expected (unlike the "Virtual Camera" that I appear to have - trying to work out where that one came from). For the OBS-VC I have its settings as "Output Type: [Progam (Default)]"

Comment: Did you check log files of OBS, Teams and Windows? They should tell you the cause.

Comment: @ChrisDavies thanks for the differential. That's helpful. I'm set up the same way, so that supports the hypothesis that it's a local environment problem.

Comment: @zomega I'm not seeing Teams video-related entries. Was there a specific event you were thinking of?

Comment: The issue probably depends on the specific hardware, for example the number of available GPU encode / decode queues. If you have both dedicated and integrated GPU, try to push one program to one, and the other to the other. Or force dedicated GPU for both.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (Windows 11):

- start a new meeting (with yourself)
- turn off video camera
- start OBS and start virtual camera
- try to turn on camera in Teams. Teams will complain that it can't access the camera
- on top of teams window, hit the `... more` button -> `Settings` -> `Device Settings`
- under `Video Settings` choose the `OBS Virtual Camera`
- Now you should see the video feed from OBS.

Try to quit the meeting and Teams. From now on, if you restart Teams and OBS is running, Teams should automatically reconnect to the OBS Virtual Camera.

Comment: Please note the details in my question. I know how to use OBS and Teams. I've been doing it for years without an issue. With the new app, it recognises the OBS Virtual Camera, but the whole video system in Teams freezes when I try to use it. Are you trying to say that turning the hardware camera off and on at strategic points makes a difference?

Comment: If instead, you're referencing https://superuser.com/questions/1817037/new-teams-doesnt-capture-obs-virtual-camera-and-flakes-out/1818836#comment2861367_1817037  I tried that already

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a good solution for the new Teams.
There are other reports about problems with it, so that yours
is just one more. It looks like a product
which is better to avoid for the moment, staying with the
old Teams for as long as possible (or necessary).

You should file bug reports with both Microsoft and OBS
for the problem, in the hope that one of them can fix
the problem in its own product.